# wxPython Menu event - New File

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I'm trying to make a simple wxpython GUI program with basic menu functions such as New, Open and Save.
I'm able to create the GUI with right labels but when I click New File, the program doesn't open a new window. I'm thinking it's the way that I'm binding the New File function to the menu.

Here's my code:

```
import wx

class david(wx.Frame):

  def __init__(self,parent,id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'wxPython Window',size=(300,200))
    panel=wx.Panel(self)

    status=self.CreateStatusBar()
    menubar=wx.MenuBar()
    file=wx.Menu()
    edit=wx.Menu()
    file.Append(wx.NewId(),"New File","This opens a new file")
    file.Append(wx.NewId(),"Open...","This opens an existing file")
    file.Append(wx.NewId(),"Save","Save the current file")
    menubar.Append(file,"File")
    menubar.Append(edit,"Edit")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.NewFile, id=wx.ID_NEW)
    self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

  def NewFile(self,parent,id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'wxPython Window',size=(300,200))
    panel=wx.Panel(self)

    status=self.CreateStatusBar()
    menubar=wx.MenuBar()
    file=wx.Menu()
    edit=wx.Menu()
    file.Append(wx.NewId(),"New File","This opens a new file")
    file.Append(wx.NewId(),"Open...","This opens an existing file")
    file.Append(wx.NewId(),"Save","Save the current file")
    menubar.Append(file,"File")
    menubar.Append(edit,"Edit")
    self.SetMenuBar(menubar)


if __name__=='__main__':
  app=wx.App()
  frame=david(parent=None,id=-1)
  frame.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the way you used `Bind` on is incorrect. The `id=wx.ID_NEW` will make it so that the event is binded to a new ID which doesn't reference anything. However you want to use the ID of the menubar item for file, which you can get when you use the `Append` method.

```
  ...
  newFileID = file.Append(wx.NewId(), "New File", "This opens a new file")
  ...
  self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.NewFile, newFileID)
  ...
```

Also, the event handler method `NewFile` should have two only one parameter `event`, described [here](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/events_overview.html).
Now to open a new window, there's many ways to do it but the easiest would be to use the frame you've already written. Note the function parameters I'm using.

```
  def NewFile(self, event):
    frame = david(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
```

A note on style too: Try and use spaces when assigning values and values in parenthesis.
See [this](https://wxpython.org/pages/overview/#hello-world) for a good intro to wxPython.

Comment: You're welcome. Could you click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as correct.